# Override CSS Display property with Flexslider 2

Tags: jquery, css, styles, html-lists, flexslider

**I am willing to hide in the carousel div `div#carousel_container`- in my case - of  [this Flexslider 2.2 slider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html) all `<li>` of a certain class but the first one**.

The way I'm planning to do it is to hide them all (display:none) and then use jQuery to display (display:block) the first `<li>` which can be identified with the following custom attribute `data-gal-order = 1`.

I have tried several ways:

1. Add `div#carousel_container .slides li {display:none;}` in my stylesheet and then use jQuery to change only the desired element's `display` property to `block`.
2. Add `!important` to #1. This successfully hides my items, but then I am unable to switch some back to `display:block` with jQuery.
3. Use jQuery to first set the `display:none` property to all `<li>` elements and then set `display:block` to the targeted elements.

   - throught `.css('display', 'none')` and opposite.
   - or through `.attr('style', 'float: left; display: none; width: 210px;')` and opposite.
4. Executing my custom script #2 before or after the slider declaration - i.e.

   ```
   //my custom script [before]

   //slider declaration
   $('div#carousel_container').flexslider({
                   animation: "slide",
                   controlNav: false,
                   animationLoop: false,
                   slideshow: false,
                   itemWidth: 210,
                   itemMargin: 5,
                   asNavFor: 'div#slider_container'
   });

   //OR my custom script [after] (also tried with different load/ready event)
   ```

**However, my changes are always overridden with `style="float: left; display: block; width: 210px;"` added to every `<li>` element.**

I am quite **confident with the selectors of my jQuery script** as for instance I manage to add as expected a custom attribute both to all `<li>` and/or targeted ones.

But as far as changing the style="display" property is concerned I'm lost now even if
**I figured out my issue could be related this part of Flexslider script (github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L892-924)?**

Any idea would be much appreciated!

---

### ALMOST SOLVED ON 10/10/2014

Thanks to r4xz & Shikhar, here is the way I managed to solve my problem:

- Using the following class: `.hide-me { display: none !important; }`
- toggle on specified elements **before** slider declaration
- add `selector: '.slides > li:not(.hide-me)'` parameter when declaring carousel's flexslider.
- As for the unrelated side issue I evocated in the comments, it is just something that sounds a bot counter-intuitive to me: `itemMargin` margin serves not to add a margin to element - this has to be done via CSS -, but to tell flexslider how much margin between toyou added in your CSS for it to calculate automatically the appropriate slider width.

**[Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/253ekLf8/5/)**

---

### STILL ONE ISSUE : see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264200/override-css-display-property-with-flexslider-2#comment-41276906)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/253ekLf8/3/) you shared the problem can be solved by the following approach-

Toggle the hide-me class first and then initialize flexslider with the selector **".slides > li:not(.hide-me)"**.
This we are doing so that we can select appropriate images as per your requirement. Now all the width calculations done by flexslider will be based on the images that are visible i.e. that don't have the "hide-me" class. The **:not(selector)** selector here matches every element that is NOT the specified element/selector.

```
  $(function() {
        /* Toggle hide-me class*/
        var $liCarousel = $('#carousel_container li.img');
        $liCarousel.toggleClass('hide-me');
        $liCarousel.siblings('[data-ingal-order=1]').toggleClass('hide-me');

        $('#carousel_container').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: false,
            slideshow: false,
            itemWidth: 210,
            itemMargin: 5,
            asNavFor: 'div#slider_container',
            selector: '.slides > li:not(.hide-me)'
        });

        $('div#slider_container').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: false,
            directionNav:false,
            slideshow: false,
            sync: 'div#carousel_container'
        });
    });
```

Comment: Wonderful, that was the final step back I needed! Following your approach Shikhar, I was able to do the trick without modifying the FlexSlider (FS)'s script. Indeed it provides a ["selector"](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties) parameter that suits this case. It now works perfectly ! http://jsfiddle.net/253ekLf8/4/ Thanks to you both @r4xz & Shikhar!

Comment: missing comment tag closure in Fiddle; rather check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/253ekLf8/5/

Comment: Almost perfect actually... When you click on the last slide of the carousel, it keeps scrolling empty content!
Would you have an idea on how to prevent that action only in the case there is no slide after?

Comment: Awesome. Why didn't i think of that. Will edit my answer to incorporate that!

Comment: Well as my remaining issue is more specific than the one exposed here originally, I've just asked some help for it in a **[new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351155/use-flexsliders-selector-property-to-skip-some-slides-in-dom-descending-order)** and will also edit my question here if I can have the other solved there.

Comment: Got the cause of the issue you have filed in the new [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351155/use-flexsliders-selector-property-to-skip-some-slides-in-dom-descending-order) but wasn't able to reply as I don't have enough reputation to add a comment and I have not yet figured out a complete answer yet. The issue is occurring because of line 164 in [flexslider](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/master/jquery.flexslider.js) **target = $slide.index();**.

Comment: Here the [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function is responsible for deciding the proper target to which the flexslider navigates to. Now in your case, for example, if 1st and 4rth images are selected/visible out of a total of 4, then as per the current implementation/behaviour of index function the index values would be 0 and 3 as its still looking in the original list of images and not in the filtered/matched list due to which the flexslider navigates incorrectly. The correct values obviously in this case would be 0 and 1 and that is why the issue is never there for the 1st two slides.

Comment: Thanks a lot for following this issue too!

Comment: As for L.164, I'm not sure that the current implementation is indeed looking in the original list of images. Because `$(this)` L.163 reverts to `slider.slides` variable which is defined [at L.45](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L45) with the custom selector.

Comment: I know that, its jquery's index function that is the problem here. Have a look at this [link](http://jamesallardice.com/why-does-the-jquery-index-method-return-the-wrong-value/) to get the context of what i am trying to say. Also, try and hardcode the target variable values to the desired/appropriate values and you'll not hit the whitespace issue for the last slides.

Comment: I tried this dirty little hack in place of [L.164 in flexslider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L164) to fix the problem but this would fail for elements with same class names and thus was not advising this fix   
`target = $("." + $slide.attr("class").replace(" ",".")).index(slider.slides.selector);`

Comment: I got your point then – the ressource you linked to had confused me as it refers to a jQuery bug that is now fixed.
However when testing on Flexslider I can see very well the bug you are mentionning. Click on a thumbnail of [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y31eoy3/4/) and you'll see in the attached console the value of target as per the current Flexslider's implementation – i.e `0` & `3`, as i sticked to your example.
I've then been able to reproduce the bug disregarding Flexslider specific implementation, which gives the same, as can be seen in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbvbjxbL/3/)

Comment: Now reading `index()` documentation, I actually find the idea behind your fix proposal not so dirty. Strange enough, if the hard-coded version of your fix doesn't work within Flexslider implemention – returning target values of `2` **(why?!)** & `3` ([see Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y31eoy3/5/)) – , it however works when set diregarding Flexslider context – returning `0` & `1` ([see this other Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbvbjxbL/4/)). So it should work in Flexslider, but for some reason it doesn't ?!

Comment: For the Fiddles with Flexslider implementation, additions to default Flexslider script stand from line 164 to 167 of the Fiddles' JS Panel.

Comment: Finally figured out the fix. We were using the wrong selector all the while. We need to differentiate the carousel and slider elements also. Replacing [L.164 of Flexslider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L164) with 
`target = $slide.index("#carousel " + slider.slides.selector);` will do the trick. Also, the previos [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y31eoy3/5/) was returning the correct target values; 0 and 1 for #slider's matching elements and 2 and 3 (which we were seeing) for the #carousel's matching elements

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I will reply and ask you one last side question on the [more specific thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351155/use-flexsliders-selector-property-to-skip-some-slides-in-dom-descending-order).
That was the final touch I needed to mark this question as resolved. I'll edit it with a working implementation example.

Answer (score 0):

The second way sounds great, but needs a little improvement:

```
.hide-me { display: none !important; }
```

Now you can toggle the .hide-me class in specified li to show/hide element.

Comment: Implemented with `.toogleClass('hide-me')` it almost works well, thanks!
A side issue has nevertheless appeared. If the unwanted items now successfully disapear, they don't for the carousel width calculation. That is to say, for instance, if in my carousel I have 2 items out of 10 that are displayed, carousel's width is still [calculated by Flexslider](http://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L948-966) for the 10. Thus even for 2 elements displayed on a screen large enought to display 4 of them, Prev/Next arrows' scrolling is enabled, which displays empty area...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/253ekLf8/3/  with another side issue (but apparently not related to the .hide-me class) - I can't have Flexslider's itemMargin parameter to work...