# Use Flexslider's selector property to skip some slides in DOM descending order

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, html-lists, flexslider

Why can't I have Flexslider's ["selector"](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties) property to work properly when targeting slides that are **not the very one after the other** in DOM order?

Basically, I found that targeting `.testA` would **work** whereas targeting `.testB`, `.testC`, or `.testD` would **fail**.

```
<ul class="slides">

    <li class="testA testB"><img/></li>
    <li class="testA testC"><img/></li>
    <li class="testB testD"><img/></li>
    <li class="testC testD"><img/></li>

</ul>
```

**Failing** here actually means that it displays properly at first, but when clicking on the last slide of the thumbnail navigation carousel, it would scroll into "nothing" (white background)...

**[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y31eoy3/1/)**, which is a copy of the *Thumbnail Slider* official sample implementation (link enclosed in the Fiddle) to which I added classes and a custom selector. To check the various targeting options you may want to add comment mark to current selector parameter in the JS window and remove it from the following, both for `#slider` & `#carousel` divs.

Comment: Issue also reported at [Flexslider's GitHub](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/1213)

Comment: @Shikhar has found an interesting entry point to adress the issue.
It can be read from [this comment on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264200/override-css-display-property-with-flexslider-2/26288876?noredirect=1#comment41398961_26288876).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is occurring because of [L.164 in Flexslider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L164) `target = $slide.index();`
Here jquery's [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function is responsible for deciding the proper target to which the flexslider navigates to. To better understand and fix the issue, let's have a look at the different invocations of the index function -

> 1. If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.
> 2. If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to the elements matched by the selector.

Now in your case, for example, if 1st and 4th images are selected/visible out of a total of 4, then as per the current invocation of the index function in flexslider, the index values returned are 0 and 3 as its still looking in the original list of images and not in the filtered/matched list due to which the flexslider navigates incorrectly. The correct values obviously in this case would be 0 and 1 and that is why the issue is never there for the 1st two slides.

Thus to fix the issue you need to use the second invocation of the index function in case of a custom selector. Replacing [L.164 of Flexslider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L164) with the following in the default flexslider js file will solve the issue-

```
    target = $slide.index("#carousel " + slider.slides.selector);
```

Comment: That's great! It indeed solves this issue. I have come to [this more universal result](https://github.com/John112/FlexSlider/commit/3768df16903500266308844dd01fe726af283590) so it could be used on any implementation and a pull could be requested on Github. **Just before marking it as resolved**, if I have understood the overall reason of the bug, I missed one detail. Could you explain why do we also need to specify the container – in this case `#carousel` – in addition to the selector variable ? Here is a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y31eoy3/6/).

Comment: That is to say, why doesn't it work with only `target = $slide.index(slider.slides.selector);` ? Apparently it should : http://jsfiddle.net/8o6svoow/

Comment: **More precisely**, for `$slide.index(mySelector)` [jQuery returns](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L99-L102) `indexOf.call( jQuery( mySelector), this[ 0 ] );`. With `indexOf` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) I understand the meaning of the `this[ 0 ]` parameter, which resets the index and counts it only with matched element in `$slide` rather than in the whole DOM's parent element.

Comment: However as the full CSS path (including `#carousel`) is already taken into account in the `$slide` object, and that the first parameter – i.e. `jQuery( mySelector)` – means – if I got it well – what to search for **IN** the `$slide` object, I don't understand how comes we need to specify `#carousel` again at L.164 in Flexslider...

Comment: And eventually it also means I've not understood why `index()` [with no parameter](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L94-L97) doesn't return the expected result. In `this.first().prevAll().length` I guess it's the use `prevAll()` without selector to narrow that makes it fail to return the expected value. And yet in the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) is mentionned that this function *gets all preceding siblings of each element in the set **of matched elements**, optionally filtered by a selector.*  But doesn't `$slide` already match the wanted elements?

Comment: This might only be an OOP concept's misunderstanding actually...?

Comment: Your understanding of jquery's index function is perfect but you are getting confused with the context of the **$slide** object. The implementation of flexslider with the thumbnail slider that you are using creates same dom structures for both the carousel images view and the thumbnail carousel and maintains the sync. Now as per [L.164 of flexslider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L161) the event handler is associated with the `slider.slides` variable which defaults to the selector `ul > slides li.customClass` without the ID.

Comment: So basically $slide's selector resolves to something like `li.customClass1.customClass2` which is present within both the slider and the carousel divs. Now, since we need the list elements of only the thumbnail carousel to calculate the proper targets, we need to differentiate between `li.customClass1.customClass2` of `#carousel` and `li.customClass1.customClass2` of `#slider` and thus the addition of the id in the container selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I think they have helped me to figure out what was puzzling me within $slides object – L.45 we have `slider.slides = $(slider.vars.selector, slider);`, where `slider` is the jQuery object on which we have initialised `flexslider()` function, associated to `selector.vars.selector` not as an intersection but as an **union** relationship; this was not clear for me. However I'm still confused on why in this Flexslider script, `$slides.index('.customClass')` won't work like this simplified [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8o6svoow/)... But well it works...